# Problems trying to pre-load objects to a text file for faster load times

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, datacontractserializer, binaryformatter

I have been working on a Windows Form Control project to import into a 3rd party client software using their supplied SDK. The custom control written by yet another company I am trying to load requires sign on to a server before displaying information, which can take 20-30 seconds. In order to speed things up I had the idea to pre-load information needed by the control to a text file. Since it is not a known type it is throwing errors when trying to serialize the class.

I have a Dictionary I am using to reference back to the proper ICamera class. If I change "cam" from an ICamera type to a string, for example "cam.GetLiveURL()". It writes the text file without issue. This is the code I am using to populate the Dictionary.

```
        foreach (ICamera cam in _adapter.Cameras())
        {
            OCCamera.Add(cam.GetDisplayName(), cam);
        }
```

I have tried XMLSerializer, and it seems it has difficulty dealing with a Dictionary.

I have tried BinaryFormatter and get the error:

> Type 'OCAdapter.OCCamera' in Assembly 'OCAdapter.dll' in not marked as serializable.

I have tried DataContractSerializer and get the error:

> Type 'OCAdapter.OCCamera' with data contract name
>   'OCCamera:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OCAdapter' is not
>   expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add ant types not
>   known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using
>   the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding the to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I have tried playing around with the DataContractResolver and can not seem to get it to work, I do not understand it at all.

The code I am using for the BinaryFormatter and DataContractSerializer are straight from MSDN or elsewhere, and test fine without the custom type.

Maybe there is a better way to handle all this, and I am missing it. I am not opposed to ditching the Dictionary route for something else, or I can rewrite any amount of other code to make this work.

Comment: “sign on to a server” is a rather vague statement. Is this a REST HTTP service? Can you give us a sample response from this “server”?

Comment: It is a Network Video Recorder, NVR. It records streams from security cameras. I am sorry I do not know how better to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake 1: trying to serialize your *implementation* rather than the *data.

Mistake 2: using `BinaryFormatter`... just about ever (except maybe `AppDomain` marshalling)

My advice: create a simple model ("DTO" model) that just represents the *data* you need, but not in terms of your specific implementation (no `OCAdapter.OCCamera` etc). You can construct this DTO model in *whatever way is convenient for whatever serialization library you like*. I'm partial to protobuf-net, but many others exist. Then map to/from your DTO model and your implementation model.

Advantages:

- it'll work
- changes to the implementation don't impact the data; it only impacts the mapping code
- you can use just about any serializer you want
- you can version the data sensibly

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will work on this tonight. I have to do some research, your solution is way over my head at the moment.